# Azure REST API - 401 error when calling List Applications (GraphRBAC) focus Mode

Tags: rest, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to test the Art of the possible with the Azure REST API and I've stumbled upon an odd issue

I can't list applications, this is actually important for us as we're trying to automate some of this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/applications/list

If I try with the "Try It" Link, I get a **401 error**.

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
    },
    "requestId": "a9758d8f-194f-4089-afd9-4b1d3ffb21d7",
    "date": "2018-10-25T18:22:46"
  }
}
```

The request does have a bearer token, I can see it using Fiddler.

If I try to list say, Web Apps, this works fine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/list

For the record, the user is a global administrator

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says issue is with the token being presented. You can easily check the decoded token and see exact claims in a tool like https://jwt.ms or https://jwt.io

I think this could be a problem with `'aud' i.e. audience claim`, since you mention that token works correctly for list Web Apps api but doesn't work for the list applications.

In case of list web apps, you might be acquiring the token for a resource like `https://management.core.windows.net/` and thus `'aud'` for the acquired token would also get the same value.

Check what value for `resource` you are specifying while acquiring the token for list applications call. Since you're trying to call Azure AD Graph API.. the resource value should be `'https://graph.windows.net'`. Any other value could cause such an issue.

If audience values are correct but you still face issues, please edit your question to include a little more details/actual code related to, how you are acquiring the relevant token.

Comment: You are right but I have no control over the things that Microsoft provide.  In my code, after setting the right audience, namely https://graph.windows.net and not .com D'oh, I get a more interesting message, namely "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" but the app issuing the token has Owner role so a bit confused ...

Comment: Now that you have corrected the resource/audience.. this looks like a second issue. Make sure your application has permissions to access Azure AD Graph API.. are you acquiring token directly as application (i.e. r u using app permissions) or are you acquiring token as a user (i.e. trying to use delegated permissions).. you'll need to set required permissions under application settings in Azure AD app registration accordingly..

Comment: I had the wrong permissions set.  I had granted permissions for Microsoft Graph when I actually needed Windows Azure Active Directory